# Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[MKAnnotation]' error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've just updated to Xcode 7 and translated my code to Swift 2.0, however I have run into an issue with a particular part of my code that I can't quite figure out.

This is the code:

```
    let annotationsToRemove = (self.mapView.annotations as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    annotationsToRemove.removeObjectsInArray(objects as [AnyObject])

    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotationsToRemove as [AnyObject])

    let annotationsToAdd = objects.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    annotationsToAdd.removeObjectsInArray(self.mapView.annotations)
```

On the middle line, I'm getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[MKAnnotation]'

Can anyone suggest what I should be changing this line to?

Thanks.

Comment: `as [MKAnnotation]` ?

Comment: Nope - `'NSMutableArray' is not convertible to '[MKAnnotation]'`

Comment: I've tried that too unfortunately and it gives the error - `Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[MKAnnotation]'`

Comment: Then you will either need to create a new Swift away of the right time from your NSMutableArray or don't create an NSMutableArray in the first line - create a swift array of the appropriate type

Comment: I was able to get the compiler to stop complaining by saying `let SwiftAnnotationsToRemove = Array(annotationsToRemove) as! [MKAnnotation]
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(SwiftAnnotationsToRemove)` - but I didn't actually run it as I don't have a full project set up.

Comment: I literally just wrote that exact same code and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `objects` is `[MKAnnotation]`, you could write

```
let annotationsToRemove = self.mapView.annotations.filter { (annotation) -> Bool in !objects.contains { $0 === annotation} }
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotationsToRemove)
let annotationsToAdd = objects.filter { (object) -> Bool in !self.mapView.annotations.contains { $0 === object} }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7 / Swift 2 `annotations` is declared as `[MKAnnotation]`, a non-optional Swift `Array`. It makes things so much easier.

Now just write

```
let annotationsToRemove = self.mapView.annotations
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotationsToRemove)
```

No type casting, no `MSMutableArray`'s